# How to remove Java JButtons with a loop?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I am building a program in java and I was wondering if there is any function to remove a a list of JButtons when on is pressed?

This is what I have so far:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == button[0]) {
        for(int x = 0; x < 19; x++) {
            button[x].remove(this);

        }
    }
}
```

ActionListener is already configure and it works fine. Thank you in advance for who ever gives me a solution.

Comment: I think you want `Container#remove`, for example `remove(button[x])` or even `button[x].getParent().remove(button[x])` where the parent is unknown...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current code looks to be trying to remove *something*, your `this`, whatever it represents, from the JButton, which is bassackwards.

The key information to tell is -- remove the button from ***what***? If a JPanel, then you must do just this, call `remove(...)` on the containing JPanel, passing in the component (the JButton) that you want to remove.

i.e.,

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  containingJPanel.remove((AbstractButton) e.getSource());
}
```

The specific code solution will depend on the structure of your current program.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == button[0]) {
        for(int x = 0; x < 19; x++) {
            button[x].getParent().remove(button[x]);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
image  1)     JButton b[]=new JButton[10];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
       {
            b[i]=new JButton(""+i);
            b[i].setBounds(i*10,i*20,20,20);
        add(b[i]);  
        }
    b[0].addActionListener(this);
```

adding Buttons on Frame and setting Action Listenr to b[0] button.

```
  image 2)  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource() == b[0]) {
            for(int 1 = 0; 1 < 5; 1++) {
        remove(b[x]);
      }
     }
  }
```

1) The First image adding  buttons on Frame
2) The Second image Remove Buttons on Frame.

[image: Adding Buttons on Frame]
[image]